# Is it possible, that if a Table in a database is updated or changed it automaticly dumps into a .sql file?

Tags: mysql, database

I have to synchronize two databases, one is locatet in Germany the other one in China. Since the datatransfer from our Server in Germany to the Chinese one is to slow to Transfer the whole Database, I have to transfer only the changed or updated tables of the Database. Is there any way to instantly dump a changed, updated or created tables into a .sql file That I can then Transfer to China?

I'm very new to the whole World of mysql and databases, so ive yet only tried to dump it and insert the tables manualy witch just works fine.

Is it possible to automate this command only for updated, changed or created databases in a script or just with a mysql command?

```
mysqldump -u [your_username] -p[your_password] [Database]TableOfTheDatabase > OnlyOneTable.sql
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Doing this manually is probably the wrong way. I guess you are looking for *replication* of one master-server to one or multiple slaves. This will automatically apply all the transactions to the slave(s).
Just keep in mind, that the default replication will be unencrypted and therefore you should use a secure tunnel (vpn) between master and slave.
Also keep in mind, that there is some lag between master and slave state (can be minutes or even hours on big transactions).

Comment: I've tried it that way, but because I do not have acces to the Server where the master database is locatet on I cant do it like that. its an externel service provider where the server is located and after consultation with them I should do it the "manual" way. Therefor I'm trying to automate it with a script or a command.
I will encrypt the file with passphrases so that wont be a problem there.
The database is only ~1GB big so if I zip it, its only ~250MB big but after calculation the transfer for 250MB would still take severel hours, because of the Chinese Firewall.